# "missing operating system" error with Bootcamp on 2013 Macbook Air

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot, partitioning, boot-camp

I seem to have royally messed up my bootcamp.

I have a tiny (30GB) bootcamp partition, and was trying to expand that space. I shrank my OSX partition via disk utility, then found I was unable to see my windows install at boot.

I have timemachine backups of OSX, but nothing for windows.

OSX Version 10.9.5, Windows 7.

What I have done to try to recover it so far:

Followed this guide: https://www.amirootyet.com/post/repair-bootcamp-partition-boot-entry/ This resulted in my being able to see the partition at the boot menu, but not boot into windows, as I'm seeing the "Missing Operating System" once I try.

current partition info:

```
Mikes-Air:~ Mike$ sudo gpt -r -vv show disk0
Password:
gpt show: disk0: mediasize=121332826112; sectorsize=512; blocks=236978176
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
gpt show: disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: disk0: Sec GPT at sector 236978175
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6         
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  136718744      2  GPT part - 48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  137128384    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  138397920   39986976         
  178384896   58591232      4  GPT part - EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7
  236976128       2015         
  236978143         32         Sec GPT table
  236978175          1         Sec GPT header
```

I could just format and reinstall, but I have files there I want to save. I really hope you guys can help.